# TableView scrolls beyond the last cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have 2 TableViews in a ViewController and I setup the constraints for both of them. I have also setup the constraints and alignments. The problem is that, when it starts, the alignments work as expected, however when I push TableView1 above (to come to the bottom), it pushes the last cell more (please check screenshots below).

*[Here is a video showing the problem](http://sendvid.com/qys1dyxb)*

*[And the behaviour of horizontal inspector](http://sendvid.com/f2tmgx0f)*

**Last Update:** I thought of a workaround but I couldn't figure out how to apply it. If I can get the y position of the last row inside TableView, maybe I can force the TableView not to scroll below 'y position + row height'. Is there a way I can do that?

---

**Original question**:

It's working fine when it starts and seems as expected with last row/cell's bottom is attached to the bottom of the TableView

[image]

*(Red is TableView1 and Pink is TableView2)*

But when scrolled up and reached the bottom, scrolls more than the bottom cell. Instead bottom cell should be attached to the bottom of TableView1.

*(Blue is TableView1's background color)*

[image]

What may be the problem? How can I make the bottom TableViewCell of TableView1 to attach to the bottom of TableView1, so doesn't get scrolled more?

**Update:** I made the TableView1's height 132 and each row 44. It's creating a gap as the same size of 44. But I checked `numberOfRowsInSection`, and the count is as expected, not +1.

Why can this be happened?

---

**Update2:** I am pretty sure that it's not the code, but here is the code

TableView1 constraints:

[image]

```
let sampleData = [
    PreviewDetail(title: "Small"),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Medium"),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Large"),
    PreviewDetail(title: "Large")

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.TableView1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TV1Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let previewDetail = sampleData[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = previewDetail.title
    }
    return cell!
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.TableView1 {
        count = sampleData.count
    }
    return count!
}
```

---

Comment: Could you make a video clip of the scrolling?

Comment: I edited the question. I figured out that it's not the constraints, but it's last cell of TableView1 is scrolling more, so gap seems in between. How can I get the last row of TableView1 to attach its bottom to TableView and doesn't get scrolled more? @sschale [Here is the video you asked](http://sendvid.com/qys1dyxb)

Comment: Can you post your code for the tableview and the constraints for the first tableview?

Comment: @idocode I updated the question and added `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Can you please take a look?

Comment: There doesn't seem anything wrong with your code except missing "]" in Sample Data array. I tried recreating your scenario, but both of my tableviews are working property. Try removing all the constraints and rewrite tableviews data source once to see if there was any missing links??

Comment: Ah, missed it when copy/pasting. I tried removing all the constraints and deleted datasource, and then added constraints and connect datasource. Same issue continuing. I believe it's not the constraints, it's something else

Comment: ohh. Anyway i tried recreating your scenario using default Basic Cell. I will post it as an answer so that you can compare it with yours and find what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer. Weirdly, when I have the 'Deck of Views' as..

```
TabBarController -> NavBarController -> ViewController -> View -> 2xTableViews
```

..it was causing the buggy view. I tried recreating the issue in a dummy project to understand the nature of the problem, and it was causing the same issue on the dummy project too.

**The Answer:**

The answer is un-ticking `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in the ViewController. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Although there doesn't seem any mistakes in your code, when i tried recreating the scenario i couldn't reproduce it. I used two UITableViews of equal width and both cell of tableViews are Default Basic.
Here is the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var tableView1:UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tableView2:UITableView!

let data1 = ["First Table, Data 1","First Table, Data 2","First Table, Data 3","First Table, Data 4","First Table, Data 5","First Table, Data 6","First Table, Data 7","First Table, Data 8"]
let data2 = ["Second Table, Data 1","Second Table, Data 2","Second Table, Data 3","Second Table, Data 4","Second Table, Data 5","Second Table, Data 6","Second Table, Data 7","Second Table, Data 8"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView1.dataSource = self
    tableView2.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if tableView.isEqual(self.tableView1)
        {
            return data1.count
        }
        else if tableView.isEqual(self.tableView2)
        {
            return data2.count
        }
        return 0
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == self.tableView1
    //if tableView.isEqual(self.tableView1)
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = data1[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = data2[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}

}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem any issue for me and i am using exact code as above

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept your answer because it's definitely not the code, I think it's something caused when I use TabBarController -> NavBarCon -> ViewController -> 2x TableViews. (I am using AnimatedTabBarController on GitHub, but it shouldn't be caused of that). I am completely stuck. I created another video showing the behaviour of the TableView, please check it here. I turned on the vertical indicator for it to become clear